# Select the String value of an element using xpath , in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am completely new to selenium. I am using Selenium and java.The following is my resulting screen value. I want to select the double quoted data(Test) from this screen, and i want to replace it to a different value.

> ```
>  "value": "Test",**
>    "createDateTime": "2016-08-23T15:37:06+0100",
>    "channel": "POST",
> ```

Note: the whole data is under a `div` `class =ace_gutter`, the parent `div` class is "aceEditor".
After a long struggle i found the following xpath for that row which i want to get the value from.

**HTML code:**

**@11**

**Xpath:**
 It is this

```
[@id='aceEditor']/div[1]/div[1]/div[11].
```

**myCode:**

```
String value= driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='aceEditor']/div[1]/div[1]/div[11]")).getAttribute("innerHTML") ;
```

It is giving 11, instead of the actual text(**"value": "Test",**)from the screen. Could any one Please help me with the code. I have searched enough i am not finding any solution.

Comment: Post html code here

Comment: @Lavanya, as asked earlier, please share the HTML CODE of the `div` in which your expected data is present.

Comment: Hi SIva, Nick, I am able to print the string now Thanks. I was not able to paste the HTML code last time. i have to now replace the string value printed with a new string.  String Text =driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='aceEditor']/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[11]/div/span[2]")).getText(); This is the code i have used.  String value=Text.replaceAll(Text,"new value". will this work.

Comment: @Lavanya, are looking at replacing the value in the HTML page or just in your code for next steps?

Comment: @Lavanya, if it is in your code. it will work

Comment: Siva, i want to replace the string in the HTML page.thanks

Comment: selenium webdriver will not set value in HTML page. Use javascript for that through javascriptexecutor.

Comment: Hi, Thankyou, May I know what is the element id?

I am using the below code, but it gives unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

js.executeScript("return document.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id='aceEditor']/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[13]/div/span[2])).getText()" + replace_text + "';");

Comment: Apologies for the improper formatting, I am using Stack overflow for the first time and yet to find the formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the value in the HTML page, you will have to use the executeScript method.

```
String replace_text = "Text to be replaced";
js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('<id of the element>').innerHTML='" + replace_text + "';");
```

Comment: Hi, Many thanks, i am able to do that. But the replaced value is not retaining after refreshing the page, is there an option to retain the value.

Comment: Hi, there is no way that you can retain the value. Please accept the answer if it helped. :)